# Stop Freezed from generating toJson

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed

According to the Freezed documentation:

[image]

However, I'm using `=>` in my code as follows:

```
 factory ProductLineDTO.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ProductLineDTOFromJson(json['node']);
```

Yet I get the toJson which I don't need. Any idea how to stop Freezed from generating toJson function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be late, but according to the issues and the documentation, the right way to stop generating either `toJson` or `fromJson` is to use `@Freezed()` instead of `@freezed`

For example

```dart
@Freezed(toJson: false, fromJson: true)
```

See the [@Freezed source file](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/blob/b2ca8a5578b7ad4cd5f7f0b8df57a8ec49d157a8/packages/freezed_annotation/lib/freezed_annotation.dart#L162)

Or even the [issue where the author of freezed, Remi Rousselet, mentions it](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/190#issuecomment-1110078645)

Answer (score 0):

When the author says "Freezed will only generate a fromJson if the factory is using =>" he does not mean that it will explicitly generate "fromJson" and avoid generating "toJson".

He refers to the **code** only working if "=>" is used. So if "=>" is not used it's just going to throw an error and not generate anything whatsoever.

Also why not just delete the "toJson" after it is generated, am I missing something?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I was looking for this and find out you can do so by customizing a file called `build.yaml`
This file is an optional configuration file that should be placed next to your `pubspec.yaml`:

```
my_project_folder/
  pubspec.yaml
  build.yaml
  lib/
```

Then you can change options same as `@Freezed( smth: false)`

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      freezed:
        options:
          # Disable the generation of copyWith/==/toJson for the entire project
          copy_with: false
          equal: false
          to_json: false
```